# SQL Regular Expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I created the following SQL regex pattern for matching an ISBN:

```
CREATE RULE ISBN_Rule AS @value LIKE 'ISBN\x20(?=.{13}$)\d{1,5}([-])\d{1,7}\1\d{1,6}\1(\d|X)$'
```

I used the following values as test data; however, the data is not being committed:

```
ISBN 0 93028 923 4 | ISBN 1-56389-668-0 | ISBN 1-56389-016-X
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using LIKE.

You'll need some ORs to deal with the different ISBN 10 and 13 formats

For the above strings:

```
LIKE 'ISBN [0-9][ -][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][ -][0-9][0-9][0-9][ -][0-9X]'
```

Comment: The ISBN format is way more versatile than what you have here. See Wikipedia. This is nowhere near the RegEx pattern.

Comment: @sudantha: my solution only addresses a narrow case. Thank you though.

Comment: @gbn I think now i got the regex concept in SQL ;)

Comment: The block lengths are variable. In the cases I've used ISBN I've found it acceptable to omit the group separators (`-`) and only store the 13 digits (if `X` can be considered a digit ;) hence just one `CHECK` expression. The checksum isn't appropriate for the database because of the existence of non-compliant values used in error by publishers.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I'd do that too.

Answer (score 6):

The `LIKE` operator in SQL Server isn't a regex operator. You can do some complicated pattern matching, but its not normal regex syntax.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2005 does not support REGEX expressions out of the box, you would need OLE Automation or a CLR to provide that functionality through a UDF.

The only supported wildcards are % (any) and _ (one), and character range (or negation) matches using [] optionally [^].  So your expression

```
'ISBN\x20(?=.{13}$)\d{1,5}([- ])\d{1,7}\1\d{1,6}\1(\d|X)$'
```

Means something very weird with the range [- ] and everything else being literal.

Comment: i was using regex expression out-of the box before :-s

Comment: @Sudantha: Not full regex, only the limited support LIKE and PATINDEX support.  I didn't downvote - that was my upvote actually.

Answer (score 1):

If it splits on | and doesen't strip whitespaces, its probably missing a space before ISBN and/or after (\d|X) **here** $  .. Also, I doubt this is the problem, but [- ] could be [ -]

edit: ok, well keep this in mind when you get a regex lib/control.