# Regular expression in SQL join condition

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008

I am trying to join two tables where the the values of the two columns (one column for each tables) that I use for joining is not exactly the same,

the regular expression for the left joined table is : `^d_0*\d+` (e.g. d_00233) and the value for the right joined table is `\d+` (e.g. 233)

Is it possible to do that in SQL ? (I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008)

Comment: You can do regex in SQL with a Like clause. Pretty sure you can do it in the ON Clause of your join, if not maybe do a CTE to return the column then join on that. check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911871/sql-regular-expressions for an example

Comment: I guess there should be a easier solution than CTE , I'd like to use simple SQL !

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh, have a look at my suggestion.

Comment: I want to use simple SQL not CTEs

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh, can you check out my updates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Select * from TableA a
Inner join TableB    b
On Right(a.Column1,3)= b.Column1
```

Also you can use CTE to get length of the right joined table data (say 233) which will be 3 in length and reuse this length in the `RIGHT` function parameter where i have used `3`.

**EDIT:**

Without CTE i think this should work:

```
Select * from TableA a
Inner join TableB    b
On Right(a.Column1,LEN(b.Column1))= b.Column1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table2 b 
ON CONVERT(INT, STUFF(a.ColumnName, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', a.ColumnName + '1')-1, ''))=b.ColumnName
```

Comment: No it's not possible because it's a wide range of numbers , so you may join d_0992 in the left table with 99 on the right table (I guess ?)

The only problem is the the first two characters which are like `d_` or `p_` or `i_` and the starting 0s , so I decided to do a SUBSTRING and CAST to INTEGER

Comment: So u mean the select should not consider the value d_0992 join 99 right?

Comment: actually `d_0992` has to join with `992` not with `99`

Comment: Please check the answer with new condition `CONVERT(INT, STUFF(a.ColumnName, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', a.ColumnName + '1')-1, ''))=b.ColumnName`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I decided to use the following SQL rather than Regular Expression :

`SELECT     *
FROM         din2class RIGHT OUTER JOIN features_top20 ON 
din2class.din = CAST(SUBSTRING(dbo.features_top20.feature, 3,LEN(dbo.features_top20.feature)) AS INT)`

So instead of using Regular Expression I used simple Substring & Casting (to remove starting 0s) , it seems to be easier to use than regular expression